# Get all the rejected additions to a Set

Tags: java, list, arraylist, duplicates, hashset

I am not really good with hashsets and I was wondering if I am able to retrieve the duplicates that the hashets deleted using the .addAll method. So in my code, it ask the user to enter values up to 20 and if it's -1, break. It then deletes the duplicates and shows the finished list. But now I want to show a list of lists of the deleted duplicates. For example: 2 = 3 duplicates 5 = 5 duplicates. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class Question {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> entries = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int counter = 0;
        int sentinel = -1;
        while (entries.size() <= 20) {

            System.out.println("Please enter some numbers into the entries list");
            entries.add(input.nextInt());
            if (entries.get(counter) == sentinel) {
                entries.remove(counter);
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("You've added: " + entries.get(counter) + ". So far your list is as shows: " + entries);
            counter++;

        }

        System.out.println("The list is: " + entries);
        System.out.println("Checking for Duplicates...");

        Set<Integer> num = new LinkedHashSet<>(entries);
        num.addAll(entries); // The addAll method deletes duplicates
        System.out.println(num);
        entries.clear();
        entries.addAll(num);

        System.out.println("The Finished list is: " + entries);

    }

}
```

Comment: You can count duplicates, but a set won't count that. A set can't tell you information it hasn't stored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately for you, a `Set` does not keep track of all the items it has rejected. You will have to do this manually. A quick and dirty way to do this would be as follows :

```
Set<Integer> noDuplicates = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
List<Integer> rejects = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(Integer entry : entry) {
   if(!noDuplicates.add(entry)) { rejects.add(entry) }
}
```

Note that the `add` method returns `false` and rejects the add request when an attempt is made to add a duplicate element to a `Set`.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from [what CKing suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41895340/2516301), which is correct, you might also be interested in using Guava's [Multiset](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained). This collection was built exactly for problems like the one you descibe. You simply add elements using the `add()` method (as you already do):

```
Multiset<Integer> entries = HashMultiset.create();
entries.add(1);
entries.add(1);
...
```

Then, to count the duplicates, you could just do that:

```
for (Integer entry : entries.elementSet()) {
     int count = entries.count(entry);
     if (count > 1) {
         System.out.println(entry +" = "+count+" duplicates");
     }
}
```

A Multiset (otherwise known as "Bag") keeps duplicate elements and it can easily return the occurrences of each element. If you want the *Set* of (unique) elements, you can simply call `elementSet()`, as shown above.

Of course, that is only if you don't mind importing external libraries.

Comment: Seems like an overkill for a task this simple?

Comment: Sure, but it may be easier to read. I don't consider it the most efficient choice. Your answer is correct, just added that as an alternative

Comment: Fair enough I guess.

Comment: Actually, It may not be such a big overkill after all :) It only bears the cost of adding external libraries for a small reason. I would follow this solution only if I also needed Guava in other parts of my program

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me as if you use the `Set` only because its nature doesn't allow duplicates.

I believe a `List` could be as good as your `Set`. You are doing some statistics about your data. That's fine.

Some sample code to show your statistics by just using a list using Java 8:

1. Collecting unique values

   ```
   entries.stream()
       .distinct()
       .collect(Collectors.toSet()); // or list or array or whatever you prefer
   ```
2. collect only the duplicates

   ```
   entries.stream()
       .filter(i -> Collections.frequency(entries, i) > 1)
       .collect(Collectors.toSet());
   ```

If you prefer printing them out immediately, omit the `.collect(...)` and use something like `.forEach(System.out::println)` instead.

If you can't use Java 8 for any reason another simple approach to get your duplicates list is also:

```
// unique values:
Set<Integer> uniqueEntries = new HashSet<>(entries);

// get only the duplicates:
List<Integer> duplicates = new ArrayList<>(entries);
duplicates.removeAll(uniqueEntries);
```

If you really like the `Set` to know the amount of duplicates you need to implement your own `Set` which holds a counter for every duplicate you add.

Comment: When not sure, it is always advisable to ask the OP whether they are using `java-8` or not.

Comment: Is it really needed? `Guava` is also an answer, which might not be used (or usable) by the OP as well and it may still help others to find their most appropriate solution. Nonetheless, the message stays the same. If it's just for statistics, why not staying with a `List` instead of a `Set`? I will add a non-java-8 sample to the answer :-)

Comment: Your answer immediately becomes nullified if the OP can't use either `java-8` or `Guava`. The point I am trying to make is always ask before posting a specialized answer or atleast mention in your answer that *this solution will work with java-8 or Guava*.

Comment: @CKing Java 7 has been end-of-life for almost 2 years. I guess it's safe to assume somebody uses Java 8 unless they state otherwise.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd An assumption however safe or usafe is still an assumption. Many organisations and clients don't think in terms of end-of-life. There are many more factors in play. It's always best to ask before posting a specialised answer or atleast mention explicitly that the code will work with the latest version only

Comment: @CKing I disagree. The vast majority of the industry has upgraded to Java 8, and those that haven't should say so in the question.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd To each his own then. I have noticed that posting an answer that is specialized rarely helps the one asking because they are not looking for a specialized answer.

Comment: @CKing but it's not specialized. Java 8 is mainstream. An answer that DOESN'T use it can be considered specialized. There's no point in introducing a major language update and then discouraging people from using it

Comment: I guess your definition of specialized varies from the generally accepted meaning. I was just suggesting a way to maximize one's returns on the efforts spent on answering but I guess that doesn't sit well with some people because well, end of life right.

Comment: Who said that an answer has to be applicable solely by the OP? Isn't it better to see answers/solutions for a problem using alternative/easier ways to solve them? If they are applicable in the current project: good; if not: take the next possible solution. I wouldn't even mind if someone shows a way how to do it in Java 9 or 10 and I believe as soon as Java 9 is the default lots of questions will gain new/better answers and that's good! People will choose what is the most appropriate for them. Share your knowledge! Contribute suggestions. Don't stop others doing so.

Comment: @Roland My intention was not to offend you or to tell you that your answer is invalid. If you read the comments I made earlier, all I said was that it wouldn't harm to explicitly mention that this will only work with a specific version or external library such as Guava. This would actually make your answer stand out.

Comment: @CKing no worries, I didn't feel offended. Rather wanted to end the discussion in the comments by sharing my view on that topic ;-) seems as if that didn't work out ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you use entries.add() it will return false, if the entry was already present. SO you would need to not use the addAll() method, but add every element "manually" by calling entries.add() and count how many times it returns false.

Read more about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add(E))

By the way. addAll() also just iterates over the given list and calls add() for every entry ;-)

Comment: This helped me a lot! Thanks. So when I made it return false, I made another list to hold the valueOfDuplicate, and if there was already a duplicate in the valueOfDuplicate list, I put it into the copyOfDuplicate, then stored both lists into one whole list.

Comment: It would be nice if you would mark this as Answered if you have no more questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can create

```
ArrayList<Integer> duplicates = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

then when you add it you just check if it's already in the array and if it is you add it to the duplicates array

```
in=input.nextInt();
entries.add(in);
    if (entries.get(counter) == sentinel) {
        if(entries.contains(in))
            Duplicates.add(entries);
        entries.remove(counter);
        break;
        }
```

edit: Cking's answer is better but I'll leave this up as it may give you an idea as to whats happening since it's closer to your code.

Comment: What is happening here :(

Comment: Just creating a list of duplicates.